# Problem loading a static css file with django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to load a static css file but to no avail:

home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body%}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/style.css' %}"     type="text/css">
<div class="container">
    <br/>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.post }}
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<h2>{{ text }}</h2>
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{ post.post }}</h1>
    <p>Posted </b> on {{ post.created }}</p>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

style.css:

```
.HomeForm {
size:20;
}
```

forms.py:

```
class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
post = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'How are you feeling?',
        'size': '20',

    }
))
```

I have a feeling I'm loading the static file in the wrong place, whats the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `.HomeForm` suppose to mean, That is not how CSS and Django work.

Comment: class? .homeform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading the `css` file correctly. But that is not how you apply css classes to django forms.

Firstly, You are already giving bootstrap attributes to your field in your `forms.py`. 
Now to apply the `css` classes change the following.

*style.css*
doesnt matter what you name your classes. No need to name them same as your Form name.

```
.home-post { 
size:30; // Increase this to see difference
}
```

Now in your *home.html* add the class to your form. (Look for the comment). So now all the elements inside this container have size attribute too.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block body%} {% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/style.css' %}" type="text/css">
<div class="container home-post"> <!--This is how you need to apply-->
    <br/>
    <form method="post"> 
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form.post }}
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <h2>{{ text }}</h2> {% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{ post.post }}</h1>
    <p>Posted on {{ post.created }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT: 
Looks like you're using bootstrap but don't seem to load it. Add bootstrap if you didn't already add it in your `base.html`

Comment: Did you change your attribute to something else in `style.css`? because your form is already at size 20.  And make sure you are not running another project which has same file name, Browser will just load it from the cache instead of reloading.

Comment: Try changing `size:20;` to `font-size:20px`

Comment: You need to apply specific CSS to posts also. So make another class for posts and add attributes that you need for it and apply it on html.